# What is the proper notation for an infinitely repeating exponent?

Tags: notation, exponentiation

What is the proper notation for an infinitely repeating exponent? Such as:

[image]

Comment: Speaking strictly only for myself: I think the notation you have is just fine. I'd just worry about how to properly set it in TeX.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).

The notation $^n 3$ is used to stand for $3^{3^{3^\ldots}}$ with $n$ iterations.

Therefore your example would be $$x^{3^{3^{3^\ldots}}}=x^{^n 3}$$

Comment: Oh, when I said "repeating exponents" I meant "infinitely repeating exponents", as in 3.333... 

So, in that case, would I replace the n with ∞?

Comment: @ThomBlairIII You could write "$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x^{{}^n3}$." However, note that in general that expression won't behave nicely: if $\vert x\vert>1$ then it diverges, if $\vert x\vert<1$ it converges $0$, if $x=1$ it converges to $1$, and if $x=-1$ it diverges as well.

Comment: Why would it not make sense? Wouldn't the answer be "not infinity, but be asymptotic to infinity"?

Comment: @ThomBlairIII "Wouldn't the answer not be infinity, but be asymptotic to infinity?" I'm not sure what that means. The *sequence* $(x^{{}^n3})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ tends to infinity, but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x^{{}^n3}$ simply *is* equal to infinity (assuming we're working in the extended real line).

Comment: @Noah Sorry about my comment "wouldn't the answer not be infinity, but be asymptotic to infinity?" I'm not a mathematician, I am interested in things like fractals, Cantor Dust, Sierpinski Carpet, etc, and this idea of infinitely repeating exponents reminded me of something that is not exactly infinity, but close to it. Just like Cantor Dust never reaches 0, just sort of close to zero.